# Specifying html attributes with form_for helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to specify html attributes while using the form_for helper methods?

For example:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %> 
   <%= f.label :username%>
   <%= f.text_field :username %>
   <%= f.submit "Signn Up" %>
<% end %>
```

How would I go about specifying the class for the label? Is it possible, or do I have to resort to label()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On mostly helpers, the last arg is a hash of html options for the element.

```
   <%= f.label :username, "Username", :class => "class" %>
```

Comment: I had tried that, it just generates the following:

<label for="user_username">classinlined</label>

Comment: The updated answer throws an ArgumentError with the message: "wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)"

That does work if I use just the label method instead of f.label... in which case the answer to my original question is "No, you cant use the f.label method"

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, was taking the docs from FormHelper instead of FormBuilder class.